# Event Order: Application AfterCalculate and Worksheet Change

Tags: excel, vba, event-handling

I have the following code in ThisWorkbook

```
Public WithEvents Excel_App_Event As Application*

Private Sub Excel_App_Event_AfterCalculate()
  MsgBox "In the Application, Event : AfterCalculate"
End Sub

Private Sub Excel_App_Event_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  MsgBox "In the Application, Event : SheetChange"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Set Excel_App_Event = Application
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
  MsgBox "In the Workbook, Event : SheetChange"
End Sub
```

and in Sheet1

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 MsgBox "In the Worksheet, Event : Change"
End Sub
```

When I change a cell in sheet the event AfterCalculate is raised **before** the Worksheet_Change event, workbook, applications (in the right order). I am surprised because I read:

> This event occurs after all Worksheet.Calculate, Chart.Calculate, AfterRefresh, and SheetChange events. It is the last event to occur after all refresh processing and all calc processing have completed, and it occurs after Application.CalculationState is set to xlDone.

on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.appevents_event.aftercalculate.aspx

Comment: It's not clear what is your question? Do you have an actual problem you need to solve with that? That could be a but or wrong documentation, both should be reported to Microsoft.

Comment: Hi Máté, Thanks for answer. As I am new in VBA programming I have not dared this problem to microsoft because I think that I have done a mistake in my code or I have not well understood the event mecanism. Do you think I should report it to Microsoft ?